# How to output element.style.marginTop using digits only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's an `elem` HTML element, which has a `margin-top: 30px` property.

```js
function parseString(marginValue) { /* to do */ }

var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
alert(parseString(elem.style.marginTop));
```

```css
#elem {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">Some text</div>
```

If I do `elem.style.marginTop`, this outputs `30px`. How to make it `30` (without "px")?

Comment: I don't know why, but both options don't work. Trying to make question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove everything but the digits, and coerce to number

```
var mtop = +elem.style.marginTop.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9mrard4f/1/)

Comment: converts the string to a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: You may want to permit hyphens for negative values

Comment: @adeneo Awesome, now I'm going to upset you more by reminding you that these values don't have to be whole pixels either (i.e. `1.5px` is valid, current code would return `15`)

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky - just replacing `px` is fine for the example, I was trying to account for changes, like suddenly using em, %, ems, pt etc.

Comment: @adeneo: Then its need to find all symbols, which are going after digits and that's all. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var mTop = parseFloat(elem.style.marginTop.replace("px",""));
```

Just do this...

Comment: or parseFloat if it is not a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function using *RegExp* to find and return the first base 10 number from a *String*

```
function extractNumber(str) {
    return +str.replace(/^[\s\S]*?(-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)[\s\S]*$/, '$1');
}

// positive
extractNumber('foo 123456789 bar'); // 123456789
// negative
extractNumber('foo -23456789 bar'); // -23456789
// decimal
extractNumber('foo 1234.6789 bar'); // 1234.6789
// e notation
extractNumber('foo 1234567e9 bar'); // 1234567000000000
extractNumber('foo 123456e+9 bar'); // 123456000000000
extractNumber('foo 123456e-9 bar'); // 0.000123456
extractNumber('foo 1234.6e-9 bar'); // 0.0000012346
// ignores e following number but not e notation
extractNumber('foo 12345678e bar'); // 12345678
// ignores subsequent decimal points
extractNumber('foo 1234.67.9 bar'); // 1234.678
// No numbers
extractNumber('foo           bar'); // NaN
```

---

So in your use case

```
var mtop = extractNumber(elem.style.marginTop); // 30
```

Comment: I think, `[\s\S]*` can be replaced by `.*` here

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky `.*` does not match new lines, etc

Comment: You can use **`/s`**-flag in JavaScript (e.g. `/.*/s`).

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 's'` on `/foo/s;` and `new RegExp('foo', 's');` (tested in _Google Chrome_) an `s` flag is not mentioned in the [_MDN docs_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) either